Can I use subtypes from a generic as return type?
In C++, I can use subtypes from a template as a return type in a function as follows.
template<typename T>
struct TypePair;

template<>
struct TypePair<unsigned>
{
    using TypeA = unsigned;
    using TypeB = signed;

    static TypeB Convert(TypeA value)
    {
        return static_cast<TypeB>(value);
    }
};

template<>
struct TypePair<float>
{
    using TypeA = float;
    using TypeB = double;

    static TypeB Convert(TypeA value)
    {
        return static_cast<TypeB>(value);
    }
};

// and so on ...

template<typename T>
typename TypePair<T>::TypeB Convert(typename TypePair<T>::TypeA value)
{
    return TypePair<T>::Convert(value);
}

int main()
{
    auto value = Convert<unsigned>(5); // here I only need to specify the "input" type
    return 0;
}

Basically, I would like to have a similar way in C# as above. So that I define a type pair as an auxiliary type (like TypePair) and then pass only one type to a function as single parameter (like Convert function). The return type should then be determined from the auxiliary type using the template type.
So, can I realize the above example in C#? I want to deduce a subtype as a return type from a generic.

Not as such, no. Remember that reflection is a thing in C#, and you need to be able to resolve generics at runtime. There are various related features, such as IConvertable, TypeConverter, static abstract interface methods

While it's possible to do something like this for pure casting operations on reference types, keep in mind that converting float to double isn't a type casting operation in .NET, it's a type conversion implemented by the compiler that widens a 4-byte struct into an 8-byte struct.

That being said, I notice your examples are all numeric.  Is this a coincidence, or are you really looking for generic ways to convert one number type to another?  If so, perhaps numeric math would do what you need, if you constrain your types to implement INumber<TypeA> and INumber<TypeB>.

@dbc: The numerical types are only examples. It could also be a class or another type. I am looking for a way to pass only one type as a generic parameter and deduce the other from a previous mapping.

That's not what "subtype" usually means.

C# doesn't really do partial deduction of generic arguments either: currently it's all-or-nothing, unfortunately. C#'s generics are more restrictive than C++'s templates: the benefit you get from that is that compiler errors tend to be clear and predictable (and runtime reflection support).

While C# does not do partial type inference, it is sometimes possible to work around it by introducing a helper struct. So you can write something like Convert(5).To<short>().

In some cases you can achieve what you want with extension methods double Convert(this SomeType<float> value){...}.

Generics are not templates. Using primitive types as generic parameters would be a problem. However, there is one way, but it would require a lot greater effort.
Please see my recent answer. The question is about Free Pascal, but my answer is about both Free Pascal and C# (.NET). This answer schematically explains how the problem can be solved, what would be the overhead, and what would be the rationale for using it, and all that makes the solution possible but questionable. I also tried to explain generics vs templates.
